# Is there a way to make StoogeSort more curve-like?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, analysis

I'm currently studying Analysis of Algorithms and their respective runtime, and i came across a sorting algorithm called [Stooge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort), and the weird way it behaves really caught my attention. I'm trying to determine the runtime using a program created by a professor of mine, but the amount of points that i have are very small, because the runtime starts to grow in a very quick manner and i can't let my computer execute a program for an entire day.

My question is: Is there a way to make the algorithm behave more like a curve without changing it's complexity? Because i've so far calculated 5 points that would be useful (these points are the first real number after the Stooge sort "ladder" graph changes, reffering to the size of the array getting sorted), but that's not as much as i need.

I'm using the algorithm provided on the wikipedia page of the Stooge Sort.

Comment: What do you mean by "more like a curve"? It _does_ behave like a curve. It just gets kind of steep kind of quickly. That's a consequence of its time complexity.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware, but i'd like to know if there was something i could change, without messing up the complexity, to make the points in between the "steps" on the graph to not change so abruptly, change in a continuous rate, like a curve. Sorry, i'm not very good at explaining questions.

Comment: What array sizes have you tried?

Comment: up until 1067, the ones that had a change in runtime were: 212, 317, 475, 712, 1067. 1067 runs in about a minute.

Comment: @SrKurtz can you post the complete list of values and times you have?

Comment: Sure. 212 -> 0.6s, 317 -> 2.3s, 475 -> 7.6s, 712 -> 23.3s, 1067 -> 69.2s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five points is too little data to say it doesn't behave like a curve.

In fact, you can find a pretty accurate curve fit for your data:

[image: curve fit]

source: http://mycurvefit.com/index.html?action=openshare&id=7b237893-c52c-49db-bcf6-e29ccf391b7c

But, again, there is very little data to conclude anything.

Comment: That's an interesting result, the Cubic Regression. But theoretically it's a power curve. So I selected that fit method and, low and behold, it calculated a best fit power curve as ax^b with a = 4.201811e-7 and b = 2.713502 with R^2 = 0.9999. Theory doesn't care about a, and predicts b = 2.7095... per OP's Wikipedia link. So there you go, seems like a really good fit to the theoretical value.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom That result of yours *is* an interesting result :)